# Wrong resolution from imageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, resolution

I have a gallery in my application, but when i load the pictures i have the same resolution like the image below. These images are resolution 300x300. Even increasing the resolution the images shows me the same resolution..

[image]

Can you help me?

My Adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;
        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<String>  urls; 
        private ImageLoader imageLoader;
        private int largura;
        private int altura;

        public ImageAdapter(Activity acivity,Context c,ArrayList<String> urls,int largura, int altura) {
            this.activity = acivity;
            this.urls = urls;
            this.largura = largura;
            this.altura = altura;
            mContext = c;
            TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.MapAttrs);
            mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return urls.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            int largura = this.largura;
            int altura = this.altura/3;
            ImageView i = null;
            if(convertView == null)
                i = new ImageView(mContext);

            //i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            i.setDrawingCacheQuality(100);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
            //i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(largura,altura));
            i.getLayoutParams().height = 300;
            i.getLayoutParams().width = 300;

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(urls.get(position), i);

            return i;
        }


    }
```

Display Image

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);


        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }
    }
```

Layout

```
<Gallery
android:id="@+id/gallery"                           android:layout_width="match_parent"                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                            android:paddingTop="5sp"
/>
```

Comment: How could we help you without seeing your code? Show at least where you defined these dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by increasing height and width of layout in which your photos are or maybe layout has constant width and height value and couldn't be resized try to set layout width and height to wrap_content and please paste your code, because no one could help you without your code.

EDIT:

Paste your layout in xml.

ADDITIONAL:

If you want to make gallery with lots of photos don't create new ImageView for every element do it like this

```
if(convertView == null)
convertView = new ImageView();
```

This is made in order to not keep too many elements in memory and use other which are not visible now.

other way if you will have lots of images your app will be not working smoothly.

EDIT:

you should do it like this in DisplayImage method

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, false));
```

and it should work

Comment: I did the changes, but the size of images continues the same

Comment: so how you get mGalleryItemBackground object could you paste code ? maybe you shoudl try to i.setBackgroundDrawable(background)

Comment: please paste code where you get mGalleryItemBackground object. I think you should cast it to drawable and then it propably could be resized.

Comment: ImageView i = null;
            if(convertView == null)
                i = new ImageView(mContext); 

its why you have nullPointer :) change i to convertView and remove ImageView i = null; line

Comment: The images continues the same resolution... The size of bytes increased, but the resolution is the same....

Comment: And the size changed? So maybe check if you are loading image or thumb

Comment: but image resized or have the same size like on your screen ? Resolution doesn't mean size. Maybe its maximum resolution of image and you can resize image but you will have poor quality.